# repeat checkbox in table <td></td>

Tags: php, symfony

So I have this form here in a for. I'd like this checkbox form to repeat himself in every line of my table but it's only repeating the label correctly for each line.
I need a way to repeat those Three checks in every line of my table.

Here is the controller (not sure by the way that I created the builder correctly:

```
<?php
$staffList = $this->getDoctrine()
                    ->getEntityManager()
                    ->getRepository('EnsgtiUserBundle:User')
                    ->findAll();

        $formAnnee = $this->createFormBuilder()
                            ->add('checkAnnee1', 'checkbox', array(
                                  'label'     => 'test test',
                                  'required'  => false,))
                            ->add('checkAnnee2', 'checkbox', array(
                                  'label'     => '',
                                  'required'  => false,))
                            ->add('checkAnnee3', 'checkbox', array(
                                  'label'     => '',
                                  'required'  => false,))
                            ->getForm();

        //return $this->redirect( $this->generateUrl('EnsgtiEnsgtiBundle_voirList'));
        return $this->render('EnsgtiEnsgtiBundle:Appli:voirStaffList.html.twig', array(
            'staffList' => $staffList,
            'formAnnee' => $formAnnee->createView(),
        ));
```

Here is the form:

```
{% for user in staffList %}
         <tr>
            <td class="tdVoirStaff"> {{user.nom}} </td>
            <td class="tdVoirStaff"> {{user.prenom}} </td>
            <td class="tdVoirStaff" nowrap> {{user.email}} </td>
            <td class="tdVoirStaff" nowrap>
                <form {{ form_enctype(formAnnee) }}>
                    {{ form_label(formAnnee.checkAnnee1, "1") }}
                    {{ form_errors(formAnnee.checkAnnee1) }}
                    {{ form_widget(formAnnee.checkAnnee1) }}

                    {{ form_label(formAnnee.checkAnnee2, "2") }}
                    {{ form_errors(formAnnee.checkAnnee2) }}
                    {{ form_widget(formAnnee.checkAnnee2) }}

                    {{ form_label(formAnnee.checkAnnee3, "3") }}
                    {{ form_errors(formAnnee.checkAnnee3) }}
                    {{ form_widget(formAnnee.checkAnnee3) }}
                </form>
            </td>
         </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Are these people confortable with getting their personal information published on the web?

Comment: It was big mistake sorry but thx for warning me

Answer (score -2):

You can't drop HTML just in  you have to post it like this :

```
<?php 
   echo"<put your html code here>";
?>
```

and you forget to close your option tags :)

Comment: Dude this is TWIG. You cant paste php dropins like that there.